# Why was this answer deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I'm referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52884941/4875631):

[image]

In the VLQ queue, I may simply edit it, to put the `npm cache clean --force` into a code block for a bit more readability. I do agree that this question is a bit low quality, but this does attempt to answer the question, and IMO if it wasn't very useful, this should have been downvoted: Not deleted.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I might have been too overzealous in trying to tame the flags in the mod queues this week, and the answer seemed to look like a one-liner with a URL due to the fact that by default only a plain condensed summary of each post without any formatting, hyperlinks, or line breaks are displayed (yeah we could have slightly better tooling for that - which [I have been trying to improve](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/)).

Example of post in mod flag queue:

> [image]

Okay, enough blaming the tools. I am at fault for not paying close enough attention.

The post is now undeleted and [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52884941/revisions).

Comment: I removed all the comments from this answer as they were distracting from the point at hand. If you have an issue with a moderator's actions either create a new meta question or (if it's more serious) use the "contact us" form to raise the issue directly with the community team.

Comment: Sam I'm grateful to have you as a mod. You work so hard and the scripts you write make our lives easier. For the number of flags you handle, your success rate is high. Thank you for being such an awesome and capable person on here.