# Why was "Convert Decimal to Double?" deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I noticed that the [second question ever asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/convert-decimal-to-double) on Stack Overflow was deleted a few months ago.

I'm curious as to why.

I don't see anything about it to make it worthy of moderator deletion.

[image]

Comment: After ten-plus years and only 38,000 views, one could argue that nothing of value was really lost here, but there's nothing in the question itself that I could see justifying it's *deletion*.  *Maybe* a historical lock, but deletion seems like a nuclear option.

Comment: @Makoto - one could argue that if one wanted to. But 38,000 views isn't too shabby and I would hope that there was some expected benefit from deleting it that can be explained.  After all an automated process could simply delete old questions with less than stratospheric view count if that is an actual site policy

Comment: Why we need to unearth question #2?

Comment: @Braiam - the question here is what was the reason/policy behind putting it under the earth in the first place?

Comment: @Braiam You need a reason to delete content, not a reason _not_ to delete it. Its ID is not really relevant.

Comment: I guess this has something to do with that account being Jeff Atwood's test account.

Comment: @ayhan - maybe. But the question had survived on its merits for 10 years without anyone caring whether "Eggs McLaren" is a real person or not and yielded some highly voted answers.

Comment: @ayhan Whether the account was a human or not isn't a reason to delete a perfectly valid question, as long as it's not used for gaming the system.

Comment: Also, if the *account* was the problem then the account should have been either deleted (not my preferred option) or merged with Jeff's main account (or another of his sockpuppets); deleting a valid - albeit not outstanding - question after ten years seems unnecessary (unless the OP wanted/needed to delete it for some reason, which wasn't the case here and, even then, would be a poor outcome).

Comment: I was speculating that he might have requested it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5/2285236) was also deleted. The dates are also strange. Maybe questions got merged?

Comment: maybe someone flagged it as puppetry as Jeff had an answer on that same Q. though that answer was self deleted for ages.

Comment: Ah, [Eggs McLaren](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301404/why-the-name-eggs-mclaren)

Comment: @machavity. this wasn't my question

Comment: @MartinSmith A moderator deleted your question. The previous title was too vague to figure out what you were asking. The title should help ensure the moderator who deleted the question gives you an answer

Comment: @Machavity the "your" and "mine" are incorrect. I didnt ask the original Q but your revised title indicated I did.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I need a reason to keep stuff. Otherwise I just throw it away. Do you keep stuff you don't need anymore?

Comment: @Braiam it's not about throwing away **your** stuff. Telling other people that they don't need **their** stuff is... bold.

Comment: What exactly is so compelling about this question that it needs to be saved?  At first glance, it appears to be a routine question about casting and why VB seems to be a bit smarter than C# in this particular scenario.  Not completely uninteresting, but not exactly earth-shattering either.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So you are saying a moderator deleted it because they didn't find it interesting enough? I am asking the reason for deletion.

Comment: No, that's not what I am saying.  How did you get that out of my comment?  I don't presume to know the mind of another moderator, and I'm certainly not a mind-reader, so I don't know the motivation behind the deletion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's what I get out of your first comment as well.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I thought the consensus was to focus on new stuff with active moderation. Plenty of new active posts that are even less earth-shattering then the question currently under discussion? Or it must have been flagged for the upteenth time that the mod-team got sick of it and to reduce workload, deleted it.

Comment: Hm, well there are, in actual fact, *seventy-nine* flags on the question alone.  Is the weight of that level of moderation justified by the question's content?

Comment: @RobertHarvey well, at least we have some reason now. That doesn't need moar flags, no.

Comment: I didn't say it was a reason.  I simply stated a fact.  Don't try to read the mind of a moderator, if you value your own sanity. :)

Comment: That does sound high maintenance. What types of thing do people flag it for? Have they just moved on to the next oldest question in its absence?

Comment: @MartinSmith:  Please know that I used the view count here as a reason to *not* bring it back.  What was said before was that this isn't exactly earth-shattering as far as questions go, so I wouldn't really miss it if it were gone.  The only thing I'm interested in is the *unilateral* decision to delete it without any obvious indication that there's something amiss with the question, which is why I'm still hangin' around.

Comment: @RobertHarvey:  Since we've already established that moderators are robots, I'd presume your thoughts are encrypted anyway. :P

Comment: yep I think we are in agreement. This question doesn't explicitly request for it's reinstatement though I would expect that to happen if, say, the deletion turned out to be in error.

Comment: @rene I don't think any moderator has ever deleted a post just to reduce workload... I mean, our job is to handle flags and just deleting posts to reduce the number of flags is somewhat underhand, so pretty sure no mod has ever done it.

Comment: @ayhan that was a separate incident. The post was originally deleted by the author and I accidentally undeleted it, so I reversed it shortly afterward.

Comment: I deleted it and I'm tracing back why. when I figure it out, I'll post an answer. In the meantime, I've undeleted it

Comment: Not is that the second oldest question by id, it's the oldest real question (id #1 is a question for meta, and #2 and #3 are answers thereof).

Comment: @Braiam reacting to your (deleted) answer: in the past 6 hours since the undeletion of the question, it has received a net balance of 3 upvotes, so the premise of receiving downvotes nowadays may be incorrect.

Comment: @BhargavRao I see your honourable optimism and raise you a ["We also received flags from the system that it's been edited a lot; \[so I turned the question into community wiki\]"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315699/5067311).

Comment: @Cœur yeah, the same premise why answers and questions of mine uncannily receive downvotes when I post unpopular opinions. Feelings over facts.

Comment: @Makoto So should we delete all questions that don't have an extremely high view count after some arbitrary amount of years? Seems dangerous to me, but we need to work out the details, since this would become a precedent. I know this is an oversimplification, but [your highest upvoted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30582318/5827005) (on SO) has 9.7k views over 3.7 years (about 2.6k views/y), while the question Martin Smith is asking about has 38,000 over 10 years (about 3.8k/y). In your opinion, what view count should a question get over how many years to not be deleted?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton:  It's like I said - I felt like nothing of value was lost with that question.  If people believe the same about my Rails question, I'm *really* not going to pitch a fit, but to be fair to both tags, you see about ten C# questions for every *one* Rails question.  I never said it should be a precedent, I was merely leaving it as an anti-defense of the question probably wouldn't be missed.  My concern was more for the unilateral deletion which has been explained.

Comment: @Makoto My top voted answer is 5 years old and only has 5,812 views ... so that means everything I've ever done on SO is of no value? :(

Comment: \*sigh\* I don't recall saying that the question should be deleted *because* of its low view count; I recall saying that it wouldn't be missed *for* its low view count.

Comment: @Makoto You are stating that the view count of question is so low that "nothing of value was lost", correct? Well, even though you didn't say it, that WILL set a precedent in future similar situations. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23730092/5827005) is your **most viewed** question, but it only gets around 2.4k views/y, so by your logic that means we can delete _all of your questions_, and no value will be lost. Furthermore, only the top [5 most viewed questions by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=questions&sort=views) should survive (all under 3.8k views/y)

Comment: @Makoto Also, I'd like to say that I understand you are not actually advocating deleting these questions, that much is obvious from your other comments, I was just trying to make a point that the question is valuable, it actually has a pretty high view count per year. My point was that view count is _not_ a good standalone reason to delete any question, and it's _not_ a good standalone reason to keep a question deleted.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton:  I only put that position forward as a weak justification.  A *very* weak justification.  It seems that you're intent in browbeating me on it though.

Comment: @Makoto I apologize if my tone came off as intimidating/abusive (as the definition of browbeating says), that's my bad - that was not my intent :)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I deleted it while there was a burnination, using a (now defunct) user script for mass deletions. There was a flaw in the script meaning some questions not visible on the page were also being deleted. I've undeleted it.

It happened around the same time as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375536/3956566) during the [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review) burnination [The [code-review] tag has been burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278138/the-code-review-tag-has-been-burninated).

I'm sorry about this. We don't use the script any more. My main concern is that there's not other questions unnecessarily deleted. Please raise mod flags or ask here if you find any.

Shog has created a post to review high upvoted deleted questions. [Deleted question audit 2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378437/deleted-question-audit-2018)

Comment: @MartinSmith it took some sleuthing into when I was using a particular user script. I'm really glad you found it. What a mistake. Trying to fix it is like looking at needles in a haystack. So I'll ask Shog if he can run a query on high upvoted posts deleted that month.

Comment: Thanks, I could do an SEDE query using the deleted posts table but that would still require visiting all the ids manually to see the questions and who deleted them. I imagine it should be easier for Shog to find candidates.

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm pretty sure they're limited to a small period in Oct. I could ask Sam (he wrote the script and would prob have a record of it). Can we query deleted posts?

Comment: Yes - e.g. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/957449 - that question was the only one deleted around that time and with a high score and that hadn't already been closed