# Deleted question audit 2018

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

At least a couple of times during the past year, our intrepid moderator team has gotten tripped up by a bug in a script they were using... Which led them to inadvertently delete questions they didn't intend to delete.

I'm pretty sure we've cleaned up the damage there, but it's a good reminder that deletions don't necessarily have as much visibility on Stack Overflow as one might wish. So I'm taking this opportunity to revive an old tradition: [a public review of deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51097/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2010).

For this purpose, I've chosen the 98 questions deleted during the past year that...

- ... Score 10 or greater, and
- ... Have at least 2000 views, and
- ... Have a combined answer score > 0, and
- ... Either aren't closed, or were closed within the past year

Here's the list. If you think you see something of lasting value to programmers and this site, write up your rationale in an answer below & let's discuss it (you need at least 10k+ reputation to be able to see deleted content).

```
   Score      Views       Title / link (10K+ only)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        10       2217 How to reverse engineer undocumented legacy application?                                                          
        10       2773 Is WHILE TRUE...BREAK...END WHILE a good design?                                                                  
        10       3435 Aviary Photo Editor - What are the alternatives?                                                                
        10       3505 Play Framework 2 - Downloadable documentation?                                                                   
        10       8096 Are there any ASP.NET MVC Core AJAX tutorials                                                                   
        10       9618 API to Fetch Gas Prices                                                                                         
        10      11573 Alternatives to Flash Media Server for multiplayer game development                                               
        10      15642 Rendering SVG with Delphi                                                                                          
        10      16342 Animate Text Using TextSwitcher In Android                                                                      
        10      70740 Link to download SQL server native client 10.0?                                                                 
        11       2925 C++ and Web Development                                                                                           
        11       3266 How to automate detection of copied code in large code base?                                                     
        11       4630 natural language to sql (from examples), learning sql from examples                                             
        11       4966 Simple Ajax/PHP contact form with validation                                                                       
        11       5055 How to write Tetris in Scala? (code review)                                                                       
        11       5285 Is the Bookmarklet Password Generator from SuperGenPass.com safe to use?                                          
        11      11492 where can I get c++ documentation ( maybe download)                                                              
        11      15423 Interview test: Deepest pit                                                                                     
        11      17474 Do you indent your HTML code?                                                                                    
        11      19346 Adding syntax colorized source code into a MS Word document                                                      
        11      74743 How to make chrome default html viewer on android                                                               
        12       2256 How to know which type to marshall from using P/Invoke?                                                          
        12       2628 Huge costs for the Network Load Balancing Forwarding Rules on Google Cloud Platform                             
        12       3578 What ORM do you use for golang services that use protobuf to serialize data?                                    
        12       5094 Explaining persistent data structures in simple terms                                                            
        12       5339[*] What is the difference between reinforcement learning and deep RL?                                              
        12       5903 Why are there many JRE implementations?                                                                           
        12      10548 Facebook App review need how long to get result                                                                 
        12      10963 JPA Implementation for Android Development                                                                      
        12      11158 Is Symfony a good framework to learn?                                                                             
        12      13188 image labelling and annotation tool                                                                              
        12      18464 How to know if an array can be sorted by one swap or less?                                                      
        13       4644 Story telling/building algorithms?                                                                                
        13       9656 From where to start learning spring                                                                             
        13      17267 How to schedule a task using Alarm Manager                                                                      
        14       2194 How often should code reviews be done?                                                                           
        14       3459 Convert asciidoc to markdown                                                                                    
        14       3889 Real-world programming examples of the Unix philosophy                                                           
        14      22045 iOS offline data storage tutorial                                                                                
        14      28291 Generate distinct random numbers in C#                                                                           
        15       2265 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'whitelist' of undefined                                                  
        15       3951 Karma/reputation system                                                                                          
        15       4513[*] how do you compute password complexity?                                                                           
        15       5016 How many hours of code review for each hour of development time, approximately?                                  
        16      14667 Cause of interesting android bug                                                                                
        16      49248 Good examples of Groovy APIs for RESTful web services                                                            
        17       6547 Browser-based visual editor/designer?                                                                            
        17      16550 Where can I find a list of CSS3 media queries for all common devices?                                            
        18       2088 Sorting items position using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter                                                            
        19       2946 How do I log out of Stack Overflow                                                                              
        19       3914[*] lambda vs. operator.attrgetter('xxx') as sort key function in Python                                             
        19      15110 how do you create links between screens with pencil mockup tool?                                                
        20       2235 How many real world developers are involved with the Demoscene?                                                    
        20       9388 What should be done first: Code reviews or Unit tests?                                                            
        20      15147 MSYS2 pacman can't update packages through corporate firewall                                                   
        20      36133 How to Customize Toast In Android                                                                               
        22       5073 Writing Custom CSS vs. Using Front-end Frameworks                                                               
        22       7162 Dead-simple introduction to TDD (Test driven development)                                                        
        23       6117 Is there a Google Takeout API?                                                                                   
        23      21920 Invalid column name in Management Studio but query succeeds                                                     
        24      46232 IDE for developing in ActionScript (Flash). Any suggestions?                                                       
        26      13598 fast, clean, C, timsort implementation?                                                                          
        26      14041 Successful code review strategy with SVN and ReviewBoard?                                                        
        27       9439 List of R / Python equivalents                                                                                   
        27      19687 Difference between Angular-4 and Angular-5                                                                      
        28      13050 NVM or N or Something else to upgrade Node.js?                                                                  
        28      18738 Is there an API for Amazon Cloud (Drive and Player)?                                                             
        28      37848 Electron App with Database                                                                                      
        29       6047 Scope of variables in C#                                                                                         
        29       6935 How to generate a guitar note                                                                                     
        30      13177 ReactNative VS NativeScript: What's advantages?                                                                 
        32      13765[*] Where should I put documentation comments?                                                                       
        32      55025 Using git for Code Reviews?                                                                                      
        33      16860 When to return bool, throw an Exception and which exception to throw                                             
        33      40386 I need a 100+ MB test image                                                                                     
        33      53116 Sample Database Design for Financial Accounting                                                                  
        33      56071 Automobile Programming languages                                                                                 
        34      71569 Where does Adobe CC store Typekit files locally?                                                                
        37      37768 How to implement a google suggest-like input field?                                                             
        37      46737 AlertDialog with checkbox In android                                                                            
        39      13858 Check for private API "usage" yourself?                                                                          
        41       2091 How do you make wrong code look wrong? What patterns do you use to avoid semantic errors?                          
        41      42520 What alternatives are there to the MATLAB Editor?                                                                  
        43      34994 Alternative to showCase library for app user-tutorials?                                                         
        44       4993[*] Is i = i + n truly the same as i += n?                                                                          
        48      32469 Is there a standard size for the Tetris grid?                                                                    
        53     223561 How to change the display of a div using javascript                                                              
        59      79131 Football (Soccer) Data Sources/API's                                                                            
        63     170528 What's the difference between a front-end developer and a UI developer?                                          
        71      19167 Best programming novel to take on holiday                                                                         
        93      75811 Comprehensive tutorial for nodejs passport local-strategy setup?                                                
        95      30508 Machine Learning in Game AI                                                                                       
       125      10887 Who architected / designed C++'s IOStreams, and would it still be considered well-designed by today's standards? 
       200      25527 What's the most egregious pop culture perversion of programming?                                                  
       211      57269 What code would you have on your wedding cake?                                                                    
       233      26727 Notifications for new Github project releases?                                                                  
       401     365090[*] The Definitive C Book Guide and List                                                                              
       826    1492260 What is your best programmer joke?
```

[*] - Question undeleted

Comment: Obviously we need to undelete and merge the joke and the wedding cake one, because I'm sure that there are many similar answers.

Comment: Do you need a certain amount of rep to view these?

Comment: @JohnHascall: yes, 10k

Comment: aaah someone cleans up those highly upvoted LOL/reddit/facebook questions at least instead of locking them! thanks

Comment: I'm curious, since I don't have enough rep to view these: Since there are "only" 98 questions here, is there a reason that this is being given to the community, rather than to the mods, to evaluate if the questions/answers meet the conditions for deletion? Yvette's answer about one of these deleted questions, and Martin's response to her that it should not have been deleted, demonstrates that diamonds are able to review at least some of these questions and determine that it should not have been deleted, rather than relying on the opinion of the community.

Comment: I think it's healthy to do things in public whenever possible, @RToyo. While most readers may not be able to view these questions, there are many who can - many more than the small team of elected moderators. And even for those who cannot, having some visibility into what gets deleted - even just the titles - provides a glimpse at how things are done here.

Comment: so this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon should also be deleted instead of locked, because 1) it's completely off-topic by 2018 standards and 2) it contains a lot of copyright infringement (cloning xkcd cartoons mainly)

Comment: This is a little... inconvenient. That's a large list of questions without much explanation as to why deletion happened. This https://stackoverflow.com/q/6246273 appears to be a simple syntax issue (? maybe ?) which was deleted by someone who answered it. Why, tho? Looks okay after a couple minutes of reading... Maybe it should be a dupe as it appears to be a syntax thing, but who knows?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Or the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/) ;)

Comment: I can't vote on any of the questions that should be undeleted.  The [code-review] and [details] tag burninations were, erm, destructive.  The sensible thing to do is to have moderators undelete them again.

Comment: @HansPassant If you see some questions which ought to be undeleted, please post an answer listing each one and why you think it should be undeleted. Just commenting about it won't get anything done.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre In regards to copyright infringement, XCKD is a bad example, because XKCD uses the CC BY-NC 2.5, and [Randall Munroe's license page](https://xkcd.com/license.html) states that a link is sufficient attribution. Some of the other answers probably violate copyright or attribution requirements though (but they might not, some webcomics allow distribution by unmodified images). A separate meta question for a deletion request could be worthwhile to determine the general consensus; if there *is* a copyright issue, deletion would probably be the easiest way to deal with it.

Comment: OK, so 10k needed to see the deleted content? Wow, what a nice reason for me to try to to achieve 10k. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @TylerH - I never mind helping to correct somebody's dumb mistake.  Powerful feature of SO, lots of potential to also correct a hundred other programmers' mistake.  Or a thousand, or hundreds of thousands.  SO doesn't have a hundred mods that got it wrong, it is just two of them.  Over and over again.  Clearly my energy is better spent elsewhere if they don't want to fix it by themselves.

Comment: Why are we even having this question? A well-received question should never *ever* be deleted, you can always close them if you no longer want further contribution.

Comment: @Graviton closing is the first step towards deletion. If a question is closed, it becomes eligible for deletion. That is the life cycle. For a question to be well-received, it would not be closed.

Comment: @Braiam - "for a question to be well-received, it would not be closed". Does a large number of upvotes not suggest "well-received" to you? There are 6 questions in this list with over 100 points. You get a gold badge for that kind of score...

Comment: @Floris it takes 1 user that fixes the question so it is not closed. Popularity (which is what votes usually reflect) is not a sign of quality. Remember, the most used language is PHP, does that mean that is that good?

Comment: @Braiam the word used was “well received” not “quality”. If votes don’t reflect this, then what objective measure does?

Comment: @Floris it is a proxy for many things, but usually, the "lowest common denominator" triumph over others.

Comment: Can't edit, but "at least 10k+" is redundant.

Comment: Note to self: add "...or over" next time

Comment: Thank you for posting this, else I might never have found *What is your best programmer joke?* 

Comment: to view post without 10K: url: "web.archive.org/web/*/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218380/how-to-reverse-engineer-undocumented-legacy-application"

Comment: I don't know when I will be able to earn 10k points in my life to see these deleted questions

Comment: Congrat to your 1000th bronze badge

Comment: @Shog9 — will there be a similar audit this year (for 2019)?  Or was the amount of contention for the 2018 audit too great to be worth repeating?

Answer (score 91):

I was (and still am) miffed that the [Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303) was deleted.  It was being carefully maintained by me and some other people.  The [Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) survives, and is entirely comparable, I believe — and is also carefully maintained.

I'd like to see the C version restored — or the C++ version removed.

Comment: Silly programmers, going about consistency and what not.

Comment: Carefully maintained?  This [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355588/the-c-book-list-has-gone-haywire-what-to-do-with-it) seems to be complaining otherwise.  (I don't have an opinion either way, not being familiar with the history of that question.)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom if you read through the comments to that question, the C book list was being maintained when the discussion was going on, but the community was not persuaded or did not notice.

Comment: Please don't delete the C++ book list. There is so much bad C++ teaching out there (bad practices, "C first", etc.) resulting in a bunch of questions from people struggling with C-style strings and dynamic memory allocation with pointers asking for help debugging their code. The list is very useful as we can point people in the right direction so they can learn C++ properly, the right way.

Comment: @FeiXiang Yes I'm sure people are going to be buying and reading expensive books when they come to the site stuck with a specific problem, especially when someone points them to a list of books to choose from ;) No, that list is useful to people already looking to buy a book. And that usefulness only increases as fake online reviews become less obvious.

Comment: This content should be on the tag wiki. It is not what Q&A is for. We explicitly say recommendation lists are off-topic.

Comment: @OrangeDog I wanted to note the tag wiki has less visibility and is therefore less likely to be viewed and maintained. Also, the tag wiki doesn't have comments, so one cannot make suggestions without editing the content. As you mention, the [help/on-topic] does say "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.", so we do have to consider whether certain questions warrant exceptions.

Comment: @Graham the low visibility is because nobody links to it. [Read Shog takes about tag wiki visibility](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370472/792066)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: As you can see in my answer to the meta-question, and my comments too, I don't agree with the observation that the list is unmaintained, and after that question was asked on MSO, I took a more active part in updating the list until it was deleted.  I made 13 or so edits to the main (only undeleted) answer, most of them after the issue was raised.  Granted, the list of C books doesn't seem to grow as fast as the C++ list; the language is more stable than C++.

Comment: Version of list from Feb 2018 via the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20180217064544/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list.

Comment: IMHO, it should even be linked from the C tag page... It does contain valuable informations.

Comment: Wanted to chime in here real quick, FWIW I am a big fan of tag wikis and I found a lot of good information / resources over the years by reading them even though they don't get linked to very much; please don't assume nobody reads those and keep up the good work! I appreciate the time people put into them.

Comment: The C tag wiki is already so big that it is almost unreadable, @jrh.  I'm not sure that adding any summary of what's in the 'Definitive List of C Books' question would be a helpful addition.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'd agree, I just wanted to leave that comment to counter the "tag wiki has less visibility and is therefore less likely to be viewed and maintained." comment made earlier; I think they're a great resource in general even if they aren't as often viewed as QA.

Comment: I've undeleted the post. Lets see it be maintained!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks.  I'll aim to make some changes (not necessarily very big ones) in 'a day or two' — sometime soon, but not immediately.  I'll also keep an eye on changes made by others.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Now the Q&A have been restored, I've added a Books section to the C tag info, just before the start of the FAQ list.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've added the background info to the question. Feel free to ping/modflag if the question text needs any further updating.

Comment: @SamuelLiew: Thanks — that's an excellent and better way of doing it than what I suggested.

Comment: Oh for the love of crap! We had an explicit meta discussion about this for a reason. There was one single person willing to maintain the list: Jonathan Leffler. I did try to poke as many C veterans as possible, though admittedly the SO format makes poking difficult. If we are to bring this list back, it must be through an entirely new post! The current list is a flood of crap with several books that I have read and would anti-recommend.

Comment: @SamuelLiew This should have been brought up in the [meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355588/the-c-book-list-has-gone-haywire-what-to-do-with-it) created for that purpose _before_ undeleting the list.

Comment: I have added a fat disclaimer on top of the wiki, so that nobody thinks that the "community-maintained list of quality books" is a community-maintained list of quality books. It was, and still is, broken with the edit mentioned in the meta thread. SO risks dropping credibility for publishing such crap on the internet.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thoughts about how we can go about moderating such a list. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379637/584518 Please give feedback!

Comment: That post says _"Please suggest edits to the accepted answer"_ but there isn't one. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 78):

I don't see why this needed to be deleted [Is i = i + n truly the same as i += n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747784/is-i-i-n-truly-the-same-as-i-n).   What harm is there in having well answered duplicates sitting on the site?

There's a frustration on the site about people asking duplicated questions, and worse still, people answering them. Then there're also some people who are keen to delete duplicates, making it harder to find them.

Comment: Agreed. Timgeb’s answer is well-written, the question decent (with MCVE).  It should not have been deleted, I’m un-deleting it.

Comment: I see duplicates as a way to make a question searchable by people who ask it in a different way. It would be nice if all the answers were stuck together somehow. Sometimes duplicate questions end up with better answers than the original.

Comment: @Omnifarious well they're hard linked, so there's easy to find once you land on the target duplicate. I've often browsed through linked duplicates like that.

Comment: @Omnifarious, A de-emphasized feature is a list of "hard-linked" posts in a list to the right. I came across this by chance since; as far as UIs go, it's one of the *less* popular places for people to look.

Comment: undeleting is the easy way. Maybe merging answers would have been another way, since questions are really the same.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sometimes questions aren't *exact* duplicates so merged answers wouldn't always make sense. If an answer contains updated code from the question for example.

Comment: I agree, I've asked a couple questions that were marked as duplicates off the bat before anyone took a look even though the related questions that were ' duplicates' of mine were unrelated. Left my question unanswered, saddening.

Comment: As a user of the site via google searches (must be 10 times a day), duplicates are often what makes the site show up in response to my queries so have to agree. Keep labeling them as possible duplicates because the link sometimes brings a better answer but don't delete unless it's really a duplicate (same words).

Comment: @Trevor totally agree and when I've been really stuck, it's those links that have often led me to the answer.

Answer (score 24):

While I accept that it's not strictly within the scope of the site, "[your best programmer joke](https://stackoverflow.com/q/234075/1967396)" is surely a question that should remain visible / undeleted. It reflects the fact that programmers are human beings, too.

And I had not come across it before - had a good five minutes of fun going through the list. Some of those were new to me, and quite good.

The site will be poorer with that content gone.

Comment: "The site will be poorer with that content gone." Precisely. It's immensely frustrating to me that this opinion seems to be in the minority, and that SO is deleting so much of its history.

Comment: To StackOverflow: "Why SO Serious"?

Comment: I believe this specific post was the subject of a near religious war several years ago when it was deleted. After the dust settled, it was brought back. (Perhaps after the dust settled long enough for the folks who had made the delete decision to feel they had saved face and stood their ground.)

Surely we do not have to be so serious that this particular off-topic post has to go away.

Seriously, in my roles as a teacher and public speaker this post has many, many times served me as a valuable resource. 
Please restore.

Comment: Why do we need to keep a list of bad jokes? Except maybe one or two, all these jokes are old, predictable, and not funny. Quite a few are in bad taste. Going through the list just made me feel depressed. Please don't undelete, because then I will have to go through it again and downvote every single one, and there are 618 of them.

Comment: I'm confused why this one was closed last year. It's been around for a decade (I think) and had a historical lock on it for forever.  I thought that meant the community decided that it should not be imitated, but that it had value and wouldn't be deleted.

Comment: Not gonna undelete this one for the [reasons I've outlined here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76584/what-happened-to-whats-your-best-programming-joke/310732#310732). It has appeared in numerous data dumps and on Archive.org; anyone who wishes to host it on their own website is free to do so as well.

Comment: @Shog9 that’s your prerogative but I think the “cost of keeping it” is a strange argument. Especially since it is apparently still around, just invisible (I can see it). What is this cost you speak of?

Comment: Cost in time handling the never-ending stream of complaints about it, @Floris.

Answer (score 18):

There are two questions I'd like to bring to attention.

The first one is [lambda vs. operator.attrgetter('xxx') as sort key function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705104/lambda-vs-operator-attrgetterxxx-as-sort-key-function-in-python) which was closed as "primarily opinion-based". While this might've been the case on older versions (Alex' answer certainly seems to indicate as such), on more recent versions of python (3.x+), there is a marked difference in performance between passing lambdas and named functions as callbacks to functions. So it is no longer a matter of opinion, one is clearly better than the other. We could either

1. Undelete and reopen this question, and then write an answer that reflects the behaviour of more recent versions, or
2. Someone in the community can write a fresh canonical QnA on the topic.

I am fine with either, but would suggest (2) because the community could then have the opportunity to vote on it.

---

After reading the discussion under Yvette's answer, I am second-guessing my deletion of [List comprehension with duplicated function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47033033/list-comprehension-with-duplicated-function-call) (not listed in the OP here). There is nothing wrong with this question except that it is the N-th duplicate of the same topic. Looking at it more closely, the answer in the dupe is more comprehensive than the duplicate target, so perhaps we can have the question undeleted and reverse the closures. Thoughts?

Comment: I agree with the first one. As for the second one - definite no *opening* nor backlinking. The current target has more merit.

Comment: I edited out the burned tag, undeleted and reopened this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705104/lambda-vs-operator-attrgetterxxx-as-sort-key-function-in-python. It lives another day. For now. ;)

Comment: "

Having dozens and dozens of variations of the same question is clearly bad.
*What we want is on the order of 4 or 5* similar-but-not-quite-the-same duplicates *to cover all possible search terms and common permutations* of the question." Having 10+ questions linked to the same question says either: people don't know how to put words in google, or there's too much information that relevant questions aren't being shown first. Usually is the later.

Comment: @Braiam Or, the current answers to the duplicates aren't clear enough. One thing driving duplicate questions is that the questioner doesn't look to see whether another question is the same, they generally look to see whether another question's answer helps them. I think we should be looking at frequent dups as a *potential* indicator of lack of answer quality (obviously in some popular areas, dups are solely signs of laziness in searching for answers).

Comment: @rsjaffe if that were the case, people would include the links to those Q&A pairs. When I ask a question, usually I've already read other [questions *and* answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6301700/792066). If I see something similar, but not the same, I explain the differences upfront.

Comment: @rsjaffe sometimes it isn't laziness, some subjects are just inherently difficult to search for. Also there's a certain minimum knowledge of a subject before you can even know what terms to use. I always assume my own search skills are above average and don't use that to judge others.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes it's easy to make accusations. Some things can be trickier to search than others.

Answer (score 16):

[how do you compute password complexity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392928/how-do-you-compute-password-complexity)

This one was closed for being primarily opinion-based, but the top answer is good and *not* opinion-based. I don't mind it being closed to prevent more noise being added, but being deleted is a shame.

Comment: I think this might make a good case for creating a good on-topic question, then merging this deleted question's answer into it so that the good answer can exist on an on-topic question.

Comment: @DavyM or just editing the current question into being on topic. OR a historical lock. Good for keeping older off topic, but worthwhile content on the site.

Comment: I've undeleted it and placed a historical lock on it for now. It could be made into a community wiki. I should add, when I deleted that I had ambivalence, as the top answer it good.

Comment: @YvetteColomb why!!!!!! You are making me do more work fixing your absurd actions. If you are going to undelete and lock everything so liberally, do delete and unlock with the same zeal! You just prevented others from doing the best course of action: fixing. And worse yet, all of them are opinion based questions!

Comment: I don't see how it's opinion based. The question is just asking 'how',  shows one possible way and states some perceived problems with it. It explicitly avoids asking 'what's the best way'. Questions that allow multiple answers are not always opinion-based. This one has an accepted answer that provides an objective metric, and this answer has 3 times more upvotes than the next best answer. There's nothing opinion-based in it.

Comment: @artem "Does anyone here has experience with this kind of problems?" and "How would you add a dictionary to detect common words?" are different questions. If the first doesn't strike you as asking for opinions, I don't know what would.

Comment: @Braiam "Does anyone here has experience with this kind of problems?" Is clearly off topic, colloquially friendly, and can be edited out without affecting the question's real meaning. I don't understand the need for hyperbole in describing this as though it makes the entire question opinion based?

Answer (score 8):

@Shog9

You undeleted [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) as per one request in this thread. I have tried hard to make the community interested in maintaining this list for several years, unsuccessfully.

After radical edits 2018 by a mod that (mostly accidentally) turned a bad post even worse, the post was deleted as per meta discussion [The C book list has gone haywire. What to do with it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355588/the-c-book-list-has-gone-haywire-what-to-do-with-it) TL;DR of that discussion:

- The content of post is of very low quality
- The post is blantantly off-topic on SO.
- The post is not receiving anywhere near sufficient maintenance by the community.

After your undeletion without prior discussion on meta, all the problems with the post persist. After the undeletion, I made a [suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379637/584518) in the linked discussion for how to improve the quality to some sort of acceptable minimum. Again with almost no interest from the community other than "we shouldn't do book lists".

And so 5 months after undeletion, all the problems with the post remain. Ignoring that it is off-topic in the first place, it is a harmful list of crap we shouldn't recommend *anyone* to read, least of all beginners. Users are still not moderating it. Crap like this will ultimately make SO lose rank and credibility in search engines.

Since you undeleted the post, I believe the responsibility of this post now falls on you - as the community evidently won't touch it. What do you propose to do with it?

Comment: He won't have much of a shot at it until you convince your fellow [c] tag denizens to stop giving him crap about deleting it.  But sure, that's hard to do.  It is the kind of tag where newbies constantly collide with veterans that have been doing C for decades and want to tell them to sod off and go read a book.  And haven't themselves read a book about it in ages, so they are not going to make that book list better.

Comment: @HansPassant Which is why we shouldn't delete or undelete stuff like this without discussing it first. This _was_ discussed before deletion, with a majority agreeing. And then an SO employee undid it all without any discussion, same story as [the list of random books](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295460/delete-the-list-of-random-books). My impression is that they want to preserve these, not for the value of the post, but for click-baiting random people from Google.

Comment: Welcome to the one year anniversary of this fiasco undeletion. The post remains unmaintained. Harmful crap like "Sams Teach Yourself C in 21 Days ", "Object-oriented programming with ANSI-C" and so on, remains recommended.

Comment: I dispute the unmaintained assertion. I maintain it. In fact I edited it today — before coming to see what is new in this Q&A. If there are specific books you think need to be removed, and you're unwilling to do the edit yourself, email me (see my profile). There are still some books on the list that I've not had a chance to review — I have a limited budget for buying books for review. I have reservations about some (e.g. one from 1989, another from 1993; probably some more). There are others which if you argued to delete, I would argue should be kept — those will invariably be ones I've read.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's not enough to have one or two people do it. We need to radically remove more than half of the list, because the things that ended up as "recommendations" after the moderator post-merge fiasco were just books mentioned by one single person, not books that should be on a list of recommendations. Everything that can be said about the matter has already been said [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379637/584518), where I did one last attempt to make the community interested in getting some resemblance of quality back. Sure, I can just edit it unanimously...

Answer (score 6):

https://stackoverflow.com/q/6246273

I can only see a screenshot of this question, but while the original question contains a typographical error due to a misunderstanding of how the setting works, the correct way to do this is nevertheless not perfectly intuitive unless you are familiar with editing styles programmatically in JS due to the nuances of CSS values and how browsers handle the loose validation in JS.

I'm not entirely sure why it was deleted otherwise. If there's a specific reason aside from "typo" I'd defer to that instead.

Comment: Not my definition of "typo", OP had wrong code, probably a misstake, nice find!

Comment: The question is probably useful for the answers, because the answers were (mostly) given prior to the question having a MCVE. However, the actual question, including MCVE, is a duplicate of the canonical "my script ran before the elements existed" questions. Given that the question edit adding a MCVE significantly changed the question, and, at the time, invalidated all the existing answers, the edit should have been rolled-back.

Comment: There are [various versions of the question page available from archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246273/how-to-change-the-display-of-a-div-using-javascript).

Comment: @Makyen or just keep the whole thing under 6 and ask a better question where those answers apply. That is, if you are actually worried about the content.

Comment: What do you think the correct way to do it is? All the answers addressed a problem that didn’t exist.

Answer (score 5):

As noted, most of these are terrible questions upvoted by people of the "me too" variety (i.e. Is there an API to do X?) or the "Should I do Y? Is that a best practice?" variety

I did note a few exceptions

- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954196/alertdialog-with-checkbox-in-android - The question itself is terrible but the answers seem highly useful. Question should be closed and maybe historical locked. 50k views</s> Sock Puppetry
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227552/animate-text-using-textswitcher-in-android - Another terrible Q with a solid A. 16k views</s> Sock Puppetry
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292882/link-to-download-sql-server-native-client-10-0 - This one seems like a clear cut case of the [Shog9 off-site link exception](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/165597?m=43207688#43207688)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525703/where-can-i-get-c-documentation-maybe-download - Another Shog9 exception

Sadly, [not even Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/686216/13) could [save this cake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc0U2.jpg)

Comment: "The question itself is terrible but the answers seem highly useful" how about asking a question that isn't terrible but the answer applies?

Comment: @Braiam if the Q had no answer I'd close and delete in a heartbeat. But sometimes a great answer needs to be saved and a +76 is not a common score for an answer

Comment: Again, nothing is preventing you from retrofitting a question that such answer would apply. Are you after keeping the score alive or the content? If it's the later, then having a question worthy of such answer is a desirable result (also, makes it easier to find and understand from the readers perspective)

Comment: The content. Score isn't everything, but 50k views and +76 answer seem worth saving, even if the Q has to be closed and/or locked

Comment: Again, the content alone could accrue those 50k views in less time that the original did because *it has a better question*. There's no reason to bring back the off topic android question with the answer to life, the universe, and everything. Instead you ask "what's the answer to life, the universe and everything" and post that answer there.

Comment: sometimes a good question is the one that brings you to a good answer by googling, no matter how the question is asked, terrible, abysimal or not

Comment: The first two will not be undeleted; these were posted fraudulently by a sock puppet for someone to answer with the aim to promote a blog. I didn't check at the time but I strongly suspect that the content is actually plagiarised.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That makes a lot more sense

Comment: *note to self*: when someone asks for undeleting stuff, ask them if the same content is available elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

The question:

- [Notifications for new GitHub project releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839622/notifications-for-new-github-project-releases)

(listed with numbers `233` and `26727`) was asked in 2013.  There are a variety of answers for resources off GitHub to manage such notifications, but I believe they've all been overtaken by events.  Sometime in mid-2018, GitHub added an extra 'watch option' to be notified of 'Releases only':

[image]

You can find more information on GitHub Help:

- [Watching and unwatching releases for a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/watching-and-unwatching-releases-for-a-repository/)
- [About releases](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases/)
- [About notifications](https://help.github.com/articles/about-notifications/)

Thus, there really is little point in resuscitating the question with all the extra options for off-GitHub monitoring of GitHub releases now that it is finally available simply from GitHub itself.

- **Recommendation** — this question should remain deleted.

Comment: Why delete the entire question, when only the obsolete answers should be deleted? For someone new to GitHub, who doesn't know about "Watch releases only", an answer pointing to GitHub's feature would be useful. Such an answer doesn't exist now, *because* the question is deleted.

Comment: @DanDascalescu: If it wasn't already deleted, then adding a new answer would probably be appropriate. Since it was deleted in October 2018, it would be perfectly feasible to leave it deleted. There are (as I type) 4 reopen votes on the question.  If it gets reopened, then adding the image above and an appropriate set of verbiage would be a sensible option.  In a sense, I've given an assessment of the Q&A — I stand by my recommendation, but won't be upset if that's overridden. (Existing answers have 276, 11, 9, 1, 0 votes; a new answer can quickly get good visibility, but not top billing.)

Comment: I too am okay with this question staying deleted.  It's invited a lot of link-only answers to services which have been largely outpaced by what is already built into GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

The question [Where should I put documentation comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4355222) was asked in December 2010 and tagged for C++.  There is another question [Where to document functions in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568052/where-to-document-functions-in-c/), which was asked in August 2010.  The latter is closed but as yet undeleted (and, IMO, should remain undeleted — but I am a bit biassed).  The 'where should I put documentation comments' question could easily be made a duplicate of the other, or the two Q&A sets could be merged into one.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do with these questions. It's the comments one that is deleted. Keep one deleted and the other one?

Comment: @YvetteColomb — one of three possibilities.  (1) Leave status quo unchanged; the question listed in the audit list stays deleted.  Or (2) the question listed in the audit list is undeleted and made a duplicate of the question I identified. Or (3) the question listed in the audit list is merged with the question I identified. I prefer one of (2) or (3), not least because some people lost non-negligible rep points as a result of the deletion.

Comment: A net score of >3 and older than two months means deletion doesn't remove the rep. I don't think rep loss should be a factor in deletion. I think it should be based on post merit alone. If you took rep out of the equation what would be your choice? Also considering no one lost substantial rep.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: "(3) merge" is probably the choice I'd prefer top; "(2) undelete/duplicate" next; "(1) status quo" least preferred — but not outrageously objectionable, especially since the was no substantial loss of rep.  Ranked Choice Voting, as in SO elections :D

Comment: I've reopened it and closed it as a duplicate of the other. The target needs to be edited to include both tags in the body (not just the tags). Are you happy to do that? They can then be merged or they can be left as is, as duplicates, but we still need to deal with the tag issue

Comment: I'll edit tags — in fact, I've done so (noting why in the edit comments), and adding a reference to the duplicate.

Comment: @YvetteColomb wait, what? You undeleting that question and making it a duplicated of another **closed** question is bizarre. Both questions are in path to deletion, just that the former got there first. Now to delete the thing we need at least 13 delete votes, up from 8!

Comment: @Braiam Just because something is closed, doesn't mean that it will be, or should be, deleted. Questions should be deleted if they are causing harm, in some way, or if they "[are of no lasting value whatsoever](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)". I'm not arguing one way or another on these specific questions. You just repeatedly effectively said that "closed" == "will be deleted soon", and that's just not the case.

Comment: @Braiam there's plenty of older off topic questions that are preserved on the site for their worth. The whole purpose of this meta post.

Comment: @Makyen closing leads to two paths: edit and reopen or deletion. You guys got too used to drag your feet around. **Each time Shog shows a list of closed questions those that doesn't get reopened, the rest gets deleted**, because that's how the system works. BTW, the no lasting value doesn't exclude that you move the information elsewhere.

Comment: @YvetteColomb and you are doing a disservice, breaking the question lifecycle and perpetuating the inability of the users to fix their questions when they get closed. If people understand that closing means that further escalation will follow, **more questions would be fixed**. Doing what you do, just enable them to not fix those questions. I presume you want only the best questions and best answers on the site, do you not? Then why prevent the system that makes sure that happens?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sorry for the noise under your post. For now I've put historical locks on both posts. I haven't merged them at this stage as it's an irreversible move and I'm not convinced it's the best move. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @YvetteColomb is not a false accusation. I'm stating facts about the consequences of your behavior: preventing the site systems from correctly functioning while perpetuating a perverse ideology. Stating that off topic questions should be preserved as they are instead of fixing them is a perversion of the original goal and perpetuating low quality content on the site. Moderators should not do that. Off topic content isn't high quality by definition.

Answer (score -5):

Why are questions with more than 50 upvotes ever being deleted by a script? There are at least 50 users who believe that this is a good, useful question that belongs on the site. Even if the site's standards have changed such that that question no longer belongs (e.g., opinion-based questions that used to be on-topic and are no longer considered on-topic — which I think is a major mistake on SO's part, but I realize I'm not going to persuade anyone on that subject), there's a reason why those questions were locked rather than deleted, to preserve their history.

IMHO, any question with more than 50 votes should never be deleted by a script, and should require actual human judgment before they're deleted. I would therefore recommend that the following questions be automatically undeleted:

```
        53     223561 How to change the display of a div using javascript                                                              
        59      79131 Football (Soccer) Data Sources/API's                                                                            
        63     170528 What's the difference between a front-end developer and a UI developer?                                          
        71      19167 Best programming novel to take on holiday                                                                         
        93      75811 Comprehensive tutorial for nodejs passport local-strategy setup?                                                
        95      30508 Machine Learning in Game AI                                                                                       
       125      10887 Who architected / designed C++'s IOStreams, and would it still be considered well-designed by today's standards? 
       200      25527 What's the most egregious pop culture perversion of programming?                                                  
       211      57269 What code would you have on your wedding cake?                                                                    
       233      26727 Notifications for new Github project releases?                                                                  
       401     365090 The Definitive C Book Guide and List                                                                              
       826    1492260 What is your best programmer joke?
```

After undeleting all of these, a moderator could look at each of them in turn and decide whether they actually do deserve deletion after all. But no script should be turned loose and given the ability to override the decisions of more than 50 human beings.

Comment: They're not supposed to be deleted by a script. The script was faulty and is not being used. A lot of highly upvoted questions have been deleted. I am also a believer of using the historical lock for questions that are no longer on topic due to the changing scope. I think it's a shame the joke questions are deleted.

Comment: There were no script turned loose. Of these 12 questions, 5 were deleted by accruing enough delete votes from users who have the privilege to cast delete votes; no script was involved. 7 were deleted by moderators, and I'm going to trust their word that no script was involved in these cases.

Comment: "do deserve deletion after all" any question that is closed is deserving deletion. The reason: the same they were closed.

Comment: "... any question that is closed is deserving deletion"? No. Most emphatically, **NO**. Historical content like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke no longer fits with the site's purpose, so I won't argue against closing it. But deleting it is like tearing down a historical landmark. Many questions that should be closed should NOT be deleted.

Comment: @rmunn you are welcome to copy that content elsewhere. Nobody would stop you doing so if you believe that it's still useful. It just isn't allowed on SO.

Answer (score -6):

I would nominate 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke for re-opening.

It brings some history and life to the site.
I realise it was discussed here [What happened to "What's your best programming joke?"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76584/what-happened-to-whats-your-best-programming-joke) 
and that the argument is that it didn't age well and took to much time to maintain.

What maintenance? And that there were too many complaints? About what? Programming jokes? underrepresented amount of people who identify as manyonaise? SQL tables who take offence?

It had a historical lock, there are some good hard exhale through nose jokes there and a lot of em funny imho and adds some charm and lightheartedness and most of all, shows that stack overflow was and is a community.

And I would think it would fit nicely in the question type: `a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development`

We developers need many jokes to hide in our code as little easter eggs for those who take over our role or people who peek at the code. That question and answer would provide good source material.

Comment: It's a terrible example of a completely off-topic question that can serve to justify posting more off-topic content. And there already many other resources off-site to get stuff like this. It simply doesn't need to be hosted within SO catalogue.

Comment: @yivi It has a historical lock, making it clear that the content currently isn't acceptable anymore, but it's kept for historical reasons. That makes it clear enough that that kind of content isn't wanted anymore in new posts, but that it's kept around for it's significance.

Comment: It's certainly not _clear enough_ for everyone. And those posts are used to ask "why X is not allowed anymore"? But more importantly: they dilute the catalogue quality and topicality, and they are not necessary. There are many collections like these on the web. Why host one more here, where it's not on-topic or pertinent?

Comment: A compromise could be to move it to meta, although it's still off-topic here.

Answer (score -15):

The SVG rendering in Delphi seems fine. There is no explanation why it was deleted and when I tried to vote to undelete it, it said that I couldn't because a moderator deleted it.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/63607

Comment: It's not fine, though, and the closure reason more than covers why it was deleted. It's a [recommendation question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question), borne out by the fact that all the answers are links. There might be a better way to ask it, but this one can't really be salvaged.

Comment: @Machavity Maybe you don't understand Delphi. It uses components just like just about every other visual IDE. I don't know what you expected the answers to be.

Comment: If it had an actual answer I'd say historical lock. Instead [all the answers are in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). The number of answers is irrelevant. The question itself is bad, and thus all the answers follow suit

Comment: You're just going to get the same question again if you delete it. Stack Overflow users don't understand these historical, nuanced limits that you meta guys put on questions and answers.

Comment: Then I would suggest you write your own canonical question and self-answer. The topic itself seems answerable, but a general `How I do X?` is going to get closed every time, especially with link-only answers. In other words, as someone who knows nothing about the subject, I can't read that question and get an answer on SO.

Comment: You're willing to delete a lot of effort and good information to other programmers simply because it doesn't fit exactly your perfect use case for SO. The general public does not agree that programming questions should be fragmented across multiple sites depending on the format of the question. That is something that you are forcing on them. If they're searching for that question, it's exactly the question that they have.

Comment: @MarcusAdams FWIW (just speaking in general terms), "you meta guys" are also Stack Overflow users. The main difference between them is people who bother to read the rules and people who do not. The former should not spend much effort catering to the latter. Stack Overflow is the site that it is because of that, not in spite of it. So trying to create an artificial schism between the Q&A site and Meta is an exercise in futility that many will see as hostile.

Comment: Many questions are not a good fit here. Luckily there is an entire *rest of the internet* where they can find a home. If "the general public" needs absolutely everything to be in one place they're welcome to put it there, but that place isn't here. Nobody is forcing anything on anyone. Nobody here is stopping you from making your utopia.

Comment: You're the dictionary trying to define the language. It needs to be the other way around. SO is a tool for the programmer, not the meta user. Let the programmers define it.

Comment: And that's how an excellent tool for one thing, becomes a collection of things that isn't good at anything. Programmers should strive for the principle of single responsibility. A programmer that doesn't do that, creates more work than needed.

Comment: That Q+A has been around for a decade, helping 15,000 Delphi programmers to solve their SVG rendering problem.  A recommendation question was not yet off topic when it was asked.  Deleting it *now* is far, far too late.  There is no "rest of the Internet" when the SO question has dominated for that long, Google hits are now down to spammy "check out our awesome product" pages.  And the proverbial experts-exchange.com hit, back with a vengeance.  Don't break the Internet.

Comment: @HansPassant: We've had this discussion, as a community, already. The post is a great example of why recommendation questions *don't work in our model*. There are several dead links, none of the answers make any case as to why their component is a good choice or how to use it, and the community rediscovered the question and closed it because a commercial answer was added to the post; it has become a spam target. I deleted it because the next newest answer was also commercial. SO is not the place to maintain these posts.

Comment: @HansPassant: and 15k views in 10 years is pretty low. We have no idea how many of those visitors left with 'oh crap, yet another unqualified list with broken links'. Just 10 upvotes on the question tells me that the resource wasn't seen as helping all that many people. Compare those numbers with [this other closed Delphi recommendation request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291631/profiler-and-memory-analysis-tools-for-delphi) from the same era.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - every programmer has to deal with memory. Only a small fraction needs to do something with SVG, especially in Delphi. Give that a factor 100 and the SVG answer was viewed and appreciated a lot better.

Answer (score -22):

Both of these questions:

```
32      55025 Using git for Code Reviews?
33      16860 When to return bool, throw an Exception and which exception to throw
```

are valid questions and I think these should not be deleted. There is required a valid answer.

Comment: your answer doesn't explain why they should be undeleted

Comment: These are not valid questions for SO, as they are opinion-based questions.

Comment: why so much hate towards his answer..... -20 really???

Comment: @Danish https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/meaning-of-downvotes-in-meta-vs-main-sites