# Why are we keeping "Where to document functions in C or C++?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-delete, locked-posts

Fallout from [Deleted question audit 2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378437/deleted-question-audit-2018):

["How should I go about documenting the functions in comments?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568052/where-to-document-functions-in-c/) is highly specific to the team. Some teams do not document functions in comments, preferring writing an actual documentation in a separated document, while keeping comments to explain the rationale of why a piece of software does what it does, others take the opposite approach and do not explain, others do both, others do nothing, some follow an style guide, others use a tool, others mix of all above.

If you find 3 programmers and ask them how they document functions, you will get 9 answers. There's nothing on this question that isn't universal. 4 answers recommend using a tool, others do not recommend tools but where, and none but Jerry Coffin answer explaining why, which if we remember, "great subjective questions inspire answers that explain 'why' and 'how'". The answers are way too short in average, for something which vary from team to team.

Can we unlock and delete this along with their duplicates?

Comment: For the guys that likes numbers, in 8 years, it didn't accrue more than 1k views per year, and shy less than 5 upvotes per year. It was closed about 1 year prior and wasn't ever voted for reopen.

Comment: They were both dead posts since they were asked. No significant edits, no new answers, nothing. Some people chatted about their preferences and it has historical significance now?

Comment: @ayhan I'm in nobody's head, but I'd hazard that was a bit of a preemptive lock so that a consensus is reached before meta strikes down on the mentioned post.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier That would require a [temporary lock](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts) though. Historical locks are permanent and *should almost never be used*: "An extremely popular question which is now considered inappropriate for the site may be locked for "Historical Significance": this alters the appearance of the question, automatically locks all answers as well, and disables flagging completely. This lock should be reserved for cases where a cherished cultural artifact would otherwise be deleted; do not use it for any other purpose."

Comment: @ayhan moderators can undo historical locks.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Sure but it doesn't make sense to put a historical lock on a post just to unlock it a few days later while a perfectly suitable another type of lock exists for that.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier note, that this was a side effect of this answer requesting for undeletion of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4355222) by the author of one of the answers on this question

Comment: It's unlocked @Braiam

Answer (score 1):

The question was unlocked and has since passed through the reopen vote review queue and is still closed. It has no delete votes on it.

[image]

Comment: As grandma's says: strike the iron while it's hot. Right now, there wouldn't be too much community willingness to dedicate attention to this specific case, the opportunity was lost.