# Why was this useful answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I just noticed by chance that this answer was deleted a few months ago:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202236/279627

I presume this happened because it's "barely more than a link to an external site". However, I think the answer was useful, since there really isn't more to say here, and apparently other people agreed.

Did anything *improve* by deleting this answer?

As a side note, I'm always happy to improve my answers if you simply comment on them. In my opinion this would be a more useful approach than simply silently deleting answers.

### Update

Thanks everyone for your comments. This was my first meta-post, and I now have a better understanding of the policies around answer deletions. **Let's consider this matter closed now** – there isn't really anything to be gained by further discussion here.

Comment: There are 5 other answers saying the same thing.  Why do you think it's useful to have the same answer repeated so many times?  Why is it such a loss to have 5 answers saying that instead of 6?

Comment: @Servy I didn't say it's a loss. I only said the answer was useful, and I wonder why it was deleted. That's all.

Comment: So why is it useful to repeat the answer 6 times instead of 5?  Saying you think it's  useful and shouldn't be deleted is equivalent to saying that there would be a loss (of usefulness) by deleting it.  If nothing useful is lost by deleting it then *the answer wasn't useful*.

Comment: @Servy I did not repeat the answer – other people repeated it after I posted mine. And I do think it was useful to have a concise answer with the link to the documentation at the top of the list. The new top answer is fine as well, but that doesn't really mean the deleted answer _wasn't_ useful.

Comment: I guess it got flagged as not an answer because it was short, and I don't know if people can see the whole context when they're handling those flags

Comment: @SvenMarnach Saying that nothing of use was lost when it's deleted *does* in fact mean it's not a useful answer.  That you think an answer that's three lines of text, and all of 13 words is insufficiently concise seems...not right.  I'd say there isn't a problem of unnecessary verbosity in the answers there.

Comment: @Servy As I said, the other answer is fine as well. I did not say it's too verbose.

Comment: you should ping the mod that deleted, he will be the only one to give you the answer

Comment: @TemaniAfif:  This Meta post accomplishes this, by and large.

Comment: at ~130K views this question probably qualifies for [Atwood cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773) which implies deletion of redundant answers

Comment: @SvenMarnach *"I did not repeat the answer – other people repeated it after I posted mine"* - Quite the injustice. Are you sure that injustice is not at least part of your question?

Comment: Tongue in cheek, it was the most visible unnecessary answer.  That brevity is the feature for questions like this is generally lost on moderators.  About all existing answers are unnecessary today, Google pinned the geeksforgeeks.org answer.  user5899929's contribution was actually the most useful one, but didn't survive the review queue since it was not formulated correctly.  You can surely rescue your answer by editing it to cover that nasty issue, programmers ought to know about that and it isn't covered by the geeksforgeeks.org page.

Comment: @gnat: See his points 2 & 4 for why this deletion was inappropriate.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit per my reading of the answer over here point #4 appears to be in favor of deletion (provably duplicate)

Comment: The real question is how a duplicate answer that came almost two years late got ahead of the original. [The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202246/5067311) which came within minutes of _this_ answer contains the same information and has much less votes. Then that should be deleted as well. Or, delete the top-voted one that came 2 years late :P

Comment: @gnat: Part four requires that the user be unimportant and the answer-to-be-deleted be posted well after the others. Neither of those things is true here (not by a long shot). Point 2, for similar reasons, requires that the deletion be handled with some measure of respect to the author, by way of _communicating_, which did not occur in this case. So we fail in two ways here. This is a well-known, high-rep user who had their answer silently deleted in favour of duplicates posted a year and a half later. That's not fair.

Comment: @Gimby I'm not quite sure anymore what is part of this question. :) I had a bad day yesterday, and felt the deletion was kind of arbitrary, so I was indeed a bit cheesed off. But I also honestly wanted to know what the policy here is, which I learned as a result of this question, and from my point of view we can consider the matter closed now.

Comment: @AndrasDeak The current top answer never made it "ahead" of the original, at least not in terms of votes. Only in the sense that it survived while the original didn't. :)

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't realized that your answer was the oldest when I was writing that part of the comment... No way to explain what happened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two users flagged it as "not an answer" at the time, presumably out of the fact that it looked like a link-only answer just because it was a short sentence of which over two-thirds was a clickable link. These flags were then handled by a moderator within 24 hours, probably on the same basis. The moderator probably didn't notice that it was neither a late answer that needed to go away, nor actually link-only.

But I'm not the one who handled those flags, and I doubt the moderator who did would even remember the circumstances surrounding this particular deletion. A shame since your answer had almost 200 votes at the time of its deletion.

Of course, any further action on my part will almost certainly stir up further questions from others on why I'd bother taking any further action on an answer from nearly 7 years ago that has no lasting value because it's just one sentence with a link and no other exposition, under a question whose other answers, albeit one of which is late, *do* contain exposition (even the most minimal) and are better for it. Hell, maybe someone will ask me why I'm wasting my time answering your question since you've already laid it to rest. Well I figured you'd appreciate the closure. So to that I say, let's just stick to answering your question for now. There's your answer.

Comment: I would add some commentary on how we handle flags to this answer, but I really don't want to have a conversation about it at this time.

Comment: Thanks, makes all sense. I would ask moderators to act with care when deleting highly upvoted answers, but from what I learned here this is the policy anyway. So we don't need to have a discussion about that, and this particular case doesn't need any further action.

Comment: Is "works on Linux, Windows, and Mac" really *meaningful* "exposition" or did you mean other (to me seemingly trivial) details added? I view this as a substantial injustice that the original first answer was deleted while trivially altered clone answers were kept! Clearly Sven is a little more mellow than me though ;)

Comment: @Chris_Rands: FWIW, I strongly agree with Makoto's assessment of the situation and I probably should have stated as much in my answer. People seemingly will latch on to anything as exposition these days, and as such my use of that word is very, very loose, regretfully.

Comment: Incidentally while Sven considers this "matter closed", I hope it does not set a precedent for the future whereby adding near duplicate answers to questions is encouraged- if Sven's original answer was inadequate, a comment or edit what have appropriately drawn attention to IMO

Comment: @Chris_Rands The reason why I don't consider further discussion useful is that [the policies that have been pointed out to me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103053/how-aggressively-should-we-maintain-and-improve-very-popular-questions/103069#103069) seem sensible, so I don't think a change of policy is needed. The guidelines were not applied in this case, but most people seem to agree that they _should have_, which is the important point.

Comment: oh @BoltClock you could undelete it and then we could address the next meta question about the undeletion. It's the circle of meta life.

Comment: @YvetteColomb alternatively: add the "**Insufficient explanation**" Post Notice to the question (like it's done for https://stackoverflow.com/q/1193093).

Comment: @Cœur it was purely tongue in cheek :)

Answer (score 5):

It covers the same ground as [another answer provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19853787/1079354).

I'm not seeing any value actually lost by this answer being deleted, but I don't disagree that its deletion seems *incredibly* arbitrary.  [Sounds familiar.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378437/deleted-question-audit-2018?cb=1)

Comment: I agree there is no value _lost_, which is why I asked what we _gained_ by deleting the answer.

Comment: Yeah; I'm saying that it seems arbitrary.  I'm not defending its deletion, nor am I trying to realistically justify it.  Just giving us an angle to think about.

Comment: But the other linked answer was written over a year later! Hardly seems fair to delete the original answer

Comment: @SvenMarnach Probably in response to an answer flag. If the flag is right, there is no reason not to delete it.

Comment: @user202729 I can't imagine which flag that might be. It's not link-only since it provides the name of the function users should use, and it's certainly not VLQ, spam, rude or abusive

Comment: Wait, so it's a first serve basis? If an employee comes first to the company but you find out that later ones are more efficient and effective than the first and you fire it, he could claim "I was contracted first"? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth [People do duplicate flag for moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266469/flag-duplicate-answers-on-the-same-question).

Comment: @Braiam It isn't right, but neither is firing the old-timer who is more efficient and effective, just because someone else comes along a year later.

Comment: @Braiam I think that both answers are "equally good" in this case.

Comment: @user202729 And per [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274826/7296893) from a moderator, those shouldn't be acted upon unless there's something else going on (such as plagiarism). Considering the deleted answer was the first answer on that Q&A, it can't really be plagiarism.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth but easy to confuse with a link-only answer

Comment: @Braiam But in this case the other answer is no better than the original provided by Sven (IMO it is a cheap copy, there would be a case for deletion of that answer instead)